# How to insert data to database in VueJs Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have project in VueJs laravel about lms online exams, so I insert webcam to take snapshots during exam is running but I need to insert this photo in database using simple method, if possible without form ? if not so there is idea to make function to press submit button automatically in timer ?

[this is the function for taking snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnMFL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: which other code exactly to provide it ?

Comment: Once you take the picture you will need to process.  Unsure about vue but the process should be the same.  You will need to send this to the back-end via ajax post to a process function in a controller. From there you can take the temp file, rename, add pic link to database associated with user, and crunch the weight.